# Facebook notification: "XYZ downloaded a photo of you"

Tags: facebook, notifications

I am a bit surprised by this screenshot I have just found on the Internet:

[image]

Is it fake?

[This discussion](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110520070714AALbyDa) seems to imply that there is no such notification.
Would be surprising but never know what Facebook will come up with next...

Comment: Create another account, friend it, download photo. Come back to first account. Do you see a message?

Comment: No notification. That's not a proof that it never happens, but I guess this screenshot has been fabricated.

Comment: Unless the screenshot also has details about when it shows, then it probably is faked

Comment: Or it could be some third-party app, and not Facebook proper, which creates that notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm also a bit worried about this. I assume these notifications simply don't exist, because I can't find any proof it does.

But it's not really nice to see this when you just downloaded someone else's photo to get a bit closer look at something in the background.

If these notifications *do* happen, then someone is going to think I am a big creep. O man.

Answer (score 0):

Nah thats bullshit.. I proved it,with another account I downloaded a photo of mine, then came back on my account and there was no notification

Comment: This is an insufficient test. I would add the second account as a mutual friend, and then download at least five pictures from a particular album.